# When was the first mention of 2053 as the end of the Third World War within the Star Trek franchise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-first-contact

In any medium whatsoever — novels, interviews, movies, television episodes, etc. — what is the first mention of 2053 as the end of the Third World War?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For TV/movie references see [the Memory Alpha entry for 2053](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2053) -- in the movie *Star Trek: First Contact* (1996) they travel back to 2063 and before they find out the exact date Data estimates they have arrived "approximately ten years after the Third World War", then in the *Enterprise* episode "Terra Prime" (2005), Tucker says "We didn't make contact with the Vulcans until ten years after the war", which would pin the date more precisely to 2053 (though I suppose it could be 2052 if it was 10 years and a little over 3 months or more, since the movie gave the date of contact with the Vulcans as April 5, 2063).

For written works, the earliest published reference given on the [2053 entry on Memory Beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/2053) is a book called [*The Sundered*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sundered) (2003), which according to [this google books preview page](https://books.google.com/books?id=5rHFB6W7mrEC&lpg=PT64&pg=PT64) pegs the date as 1 May 2053 for the date of the nuclear exchange, which seems to be what characters like Data and Tucker mean when they talk about a certain number of years "after the war".

The novelization of *Star Trek: First Contact* by J.M. Dillard (1996) also had a few references to the war happening 10 years earlier, though again not specific enough to say whether it was 2053 or 2052. Anyone with a scribd membership can read it [here](https://www.scribd.com/read/429555719/Star-Trek-First-Contact), for example here's a line from Lily's internal monologue on p. 41:

> It was hard, after ten years—a whole third of her existence—to remember much about life before the war.

Or on p. 231, when Zefram first takes the *Phoenix* to warp speed:

> Zefram Cochrane let go a scream—of fear, of exhilaration, of the purest joy—and with it, released ten years’ worth of grief and cynicism, pain and hopelessness.